# How to bind a kendodropdownlist dynamically using ajax

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a kendo dropdownlist dynamically using ajax. Could anyone please give some idea, how should I achieve this?

```
     <div id="divLocation1"></div>
```

I want the dropdown inside the div "divLocation1".

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175040/how-to-bind-kendo-mvc-ui-dropdownlist-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, this may help you:-

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { param: params },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    url: $_YourUrl,
    success: function (result) {
        var dataLocation1 = [];          
        var _optionLabel = "Please Select";
        var source = $('<div>' + _dataHtml + '</div>');
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            dataLocation1.push({ text: result[i].Text, value: result[i].Value });
        }

      $("#divLocation1").html('<select id="ddlLocation1" class="span12"></select>');
        $("#divLocation1").find("#ddlLocation1").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: dataLocation1,
            optionLabel: _optionLabel,
            autoClose: false
        });
    },

       error: function () {
     alert("Error :");
      }
  });
```